# Extra padding at the left end of action bar (after updated sdk)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding

[image]
I don't know how this padding came up, but there's no such padding until I updated my SDK to 21.
Here's my code:

```
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.title_bar_layout, null);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ? thanks.

Comment: Please post the code for your R.layout.title_bar_layout layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

since the last update of Support library `22.1.x`, if you are not using `ToolBar` the attributes have to be part of the ActionBar style. E.g

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>

    <item tools:ignore="NewApi" name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item tools:ignore="NewApi" name="android:contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and referenced by  `<item name="android:actionBarStyle"`

**OLD ANSWER**

to remove the extra padding add

```
 <style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item tools:ignore="NewApi" name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
 </style>
```

to your style.xml file. And reference it from your app theme with:

```
<item name="android:toolbarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/AppThemeToolbar</item>
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppThemeToolbar</item>
```

Comment: I used this code `Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);` and this solved my problem. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: it does the same thing, as you can see. It sets the `setContentInsets`